# Javascript Web App not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser

So I made this web app earlier and finally got all the bugs out of it...so I thought. I don't do any programing so this is really my first attempt at javascript and now I'm beyond lost. My app works fine in Chrome and Firefox but in IE nothing happens. If you start debug mode in IE, it works, but the regular user obviously won't do that.

Link to the app http://www.nst.com/voltdropcalc.asp

I'll post the code if I anyone needs it. Seems like its an easy fix but I don't have the knowledge to begin trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove or comment out the console.log statements in your JavaScript, IE chokes on them unless the console is open.

For example line 569: `console.log(volts, acdc, amps, length, awg, ohm);`

Comment: FWIW that'll only be a problem in pre-IE9 browsers where the dev tools weren't passive.